# Insert into LinkedList Alphabetically

Tags: java, linked-list, compareto

I am attempting to insert people alphabetically into a linked list by lastName. I have one really weird issue. The code as you see it works fine, except the list is in reverse order. What I can not figure out is why when I use the line of code:

```
    current != null && lastName.compareTo(current.lastName) >= 0)
```

to insert people into my list, instead of adding over 100 people I add 6. Yet like I said above I can do it in reverse order no problem. What is up with that?

```
    public void insert(String firstName, String lastName, String time,String show, String      command,int section){
    PeopleNode newNode = new PeopleNode(lastName,firstName,time,show,command,section);
    size++;
    PeopleNode previous = null;
    PeopleNode current = head;

    while(current != null && lastName.compareTo(current.lastName) <= 0){
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    if(previous == null){
        head = newNode;
    }else{
        previous.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = current;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is *head* ? the first item in LinkedList ?

Comment: head is clearly the variable that hold the first object in the linked list.  The first condition (excerpted at the top) should give you a list in descending order.  The block written to product one in ascending order.  I am not clear on which you see with each case.  And I don't understand the 100 vs. 6.   Can you possibly include data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the `compareTo` method works the other way round for `String`s, so maybe try

```
while(current != null && current.lastName.compareTo(lastName) <= 0)
```

But I recommend you to use just the `Compareable` interface and sort the list by using `Collections.sort(yourlist)`

Comment: this worked, and trust me, I wish I could use the list class. I am taking this class as an elective. At my internship I write java code only using lists and iterators etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have "b", "c", "d" and "a" as the last names. If you insert in that order, for the first three nodes it will be:

b -> c -> d

When you try to insert a, it will not enter the while loop. So, "previous" will be null. It will enter the first if condition and set the head as the new node, i.e. "a", and it will exit the method. Next of the head is not set.

So you have a broken list with only the "a" node at the end.

I did not try this but this seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out!

```
if(previous == null){
    head = newNode;
}else{
    previous.next = newNode;
    newNode.next = current;
}
```

The line:

```
 newNode.next = current;
```

needs to be outside of the else statement!